# Remove counter on weekend

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm trying to remove my countdowns from page but when I run this code it doesn't work and I don't know why. I have 17 countdowns on my page and they should be removed on Saturday and Sunday. In html all divs of countdowns are in one (#Box1,2,3,4,5...) div.

```
   <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    if(n == 6 || n == 0){
         $("#Box1").remove();
         $("#Box2").remove();
         $("#Box3").remove();
         $("#Box4").remove();
         $("#Box5").remove();
         $("#Box6").remove();
         $("#Box7").remove();
         $("#Box8").remove();
         $("#Box9").remove();
         $("#Box10").remove();
         $("#Box11").remove();
         $("#Box12").remove();
         $("#Box13").remove();
         $("#Box14").remove();
         $("#Box15").remove();
         $("#Box16").remove();
         $("#Box17").remove();
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    var timer1;
    function cdtd1() {
        var sad1 = new Date();
        var dolazak1 = new Date(sad1.getFullYear(),sad1.getMonth(),sad1.getDate(),00,40,00);
        var timeDiff1 = dolazak1.getTime() - sad1.getTime();
        if (timeDiff1 > 1500000){$("#Box1").remove();}

        if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#Box1").remove();
        }, 90000);
        return;
    }


        var sekunde1 = Math.floor(timeDiff1 / 1000);
        var minute1 = Math.floor(sekunde1 / 60);
        var sati1 = Math.floor(minute1 / 60);
        var dani1 = Math.floor(sati1 / 24);
        sati1 %= 24;
        minute1 %= 60;
        sekunde1 %= 60;

        $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
        $("#sati1Box").html(sati1 + ':');
        $("#minute1Box").html('7-Dubrava '+ minute1 + ':');
        $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);

        timer1 = setTimeout(cdtd1, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
         cdtd1();
    });
    </script>


        <div id="Box1">
        <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
        <div id="minute1Box"></div>
        <div id="sekunde1Box"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The jQuery constructor can take multiple selectors, you just need to separate with a comma, ie `$('#box1,#box2')`. I would suggest rethinking your structure though. Try using common classes instead of thousands of ids, and target your elements by index. `timer1,sad1,timeDiff1`, all those variable names scream refactoring.

Comment: How do you mean "target your elements by index" could you please explain more?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you find a way to do `$('.box').eq(3).hide()` instead of `$('#box4').hide()`. When you get your code working, try posting your question at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). People there will help you figure out the best way to write your logic.

Comment: Hi, tnx for your help, but the problem was that $("#Box1").remove(); needed to go at least place in code